# Events running multiple times after adding new content to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugins

I have issue with my plugin, because I need a way to update if new elements are added to the DOM I added a update methods,
if I start the plugin all goes well, everything works perfect, not issues, no error, but once I add a new elelemnt(div with class box)
to the DOM things goes wrong, the update works, but the click events seem to fire multiple times now, so if I add a new element the event runs
twice, if I add 2 elements to the DOM, the events runs 3 times....and so on. I am not that good at Js, so I am stuck at this, I have tried a lot but nothing seems to work.

Elements that are newly added work fine, but if I add some more new elements they will have the same issues.

I added below a small preview, as my plugin is custom an big I only posted the parts that have issues(made them easy to understand).

**The update method is needed, new elements(.box) need to be updated(add new code to the .box)**

the HTML code

```
 <div id="container">

  <div class="box">
      <a href="#" class="link1">link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="link1">link 2</a>
      <div>content goes here...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
      <a href="#" class="link1">link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="link1">link 2</a>
      <div>content goes here...</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
      <a href="#" class="link1">link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="link1">link 2</a>
      <div>content goes here...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

inline script

```
  $('#container').myplugin01();

  $('#somelink').click(function(e){
      $('#container').append('<div class="box"><a href="#" class="link1">link 1</a><a href="#" class="link1">link 2</a><div>content goes here...</div></div>'); 

      $('#container').myplugin01('update');
  });
```

the plugin

```
  ;(function($, window, document, undefined){

      //"use strict"; // jshint ;_;

      var pluginName = 'myplugin01';

      var Plugin = function(element, options){
          this.init(element, options);
      };

      Plugin.prototype = {

          init: function(element, options){

              this.elm     = $(element);
              this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].options, options);


              // example 1: animation
              $('#container').children('.box').on("click", ".link1", function(e){
                  $(this).parent().children('div').animate({height: 'toggle'},400)
              });

              // example 2: wrapping
              $('#container').children('.box').on("click", ".link2", function(e){
                  $(this).parent().wrap('<div class="wrapped"></div>')
              });


              this.update();
          },

          update: function(){
              $('#container').children('.box').addClass('someclass');

              // more code here...
          }
      };

      $.fn[pluginName] = function(option) {
          var options = typeof option == "object" && option;

          return this.each(function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              var data  = new Plugin($this, options);

              if(!$.data($this, pluginName)){           
                  $.data($this, pluginName, data);
              }

              if(typeof option == 'string'){
                  data[option]();
              }

          });
      };

      /**
      * Default settings(dont change).
      * You can globally override these options
      * by using $.fn.pluginName.key = 'value';
      **/
      $.fn[pluginName].options = {
          name: 'world' 
      };


  })(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Make sure your .click() is only targeting the newer elements. not the older ones. Given the code above, it suggests that you have duplicate ID's which is invalid and will also cause problems.

Comment: What does `.myplugin01('update')` do?

Comment: Yes, your problem resides in your `update` method, which is the one you don't posted.

Comment: @kevin i dont see any double id's

Comment: @explosion pills it mostly ads code the to the .box, add classes and wrap certain parts.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley even if I do that there still will be issues with the events

Comment: @user759235 I was refering to `$('#somelink')`, it sounds like you are running the code that binds these events more than once which is causing the event to be bound more than once, so that when you trigger the event, the callback happens more than once.

Comment: Okay no there's just one somelink Id and I added an alert and if I click this link it would just fire once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you bind events more than once this problem will occur.

```
 // inline script
  $('#container').myplugin01();// binding first time

  $('#somelink').click(function(e){
      $('#container').append('<div class="box"><a href="#" class="link1">link 1</a><a href="#" class="link1">link 2</a><div>content goes here...</div></div>'); 

      $('#container').myplugin01('update');// binding second time
   // We suggest you to unbind here and rebind it.

  });
```

Comment: I now see, yes I do bind them 2, but the second time it's needed to run a piece of code inside the plugin, which transforms the newly added elements into what I want. So if there a better way to do this?

Comment: Ah I think i now understand it, thats why some plugins have the destroy method...as this will unbind.